# extracting the integer part from a 2D string array in order to get minimum score of student grades. array contains student name and score

Tags: java, arrays

This is the method I have that accepts a 2D string array of student name and score.

```
public int getMinScore(String[][] a) {  

    String intVal;
    String s = a[0][0];
    intVal = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    int lowest = Integer.parseInt(intVal);
    int num = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) { 

        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

            s += a[i][j];
            intVal = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            num = Integer.parseInt(intVal);

            if(num < lowest){
                lowest = num;

            }
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

This is the result I keep getting:

```
Enter student name
will
Enter test score
100
Enter student name
bill
Enter test score
80
will 100
bill 80
MIN SCORE IS: 100
```

Comment: What's your question? and how do you expect from method?

Comment: looks like "s+=" should just be "s=". Also not sure your array logic is correct because you don't check [0][1] [0][2] etc.

Comment: @Abdelhak basically i ask a user to enter a name and test score of multiple students and store that information in a 2D string array. i want to be able to then isolate the integer part of the string(test score) so that I can loop through the array to find the minimum score of the students entered.

Comment: thanks for your help @Abdelhak. the code works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the minum try to use this

```
int smallest_number(int b[][])
{
  int min = b[0][0];
  int x,y;

for (x = 0; x < b.length; x++)
 {
   for (y = 0; y < b[x].length; y++)
   {
       if (min > b[x][y])
       {
           min = b[x][y];
       }
   } 
 }  

 return min;
 }
```